# Android Offline Map for specific location (Iraq_karbala)

Tags: android, openstreetmap, offline

I have an offline map with useful osmdroid library. Everything works correctly (getting image from OpenStreetMap and routing and marker and ....)

but my problem is: this app is developed for Iraq(Karbal). for this place (Karbala) Only "high street" names have been registered on the OpenStreetMap but I need more details.
I have not enough time to add map place (name of avenue) to this place on the OpenStreetMap.

Can you give me Idea?

Is there a library or another app that is useful in an offline map (even non-free)?

Comment: have you tried osmand library?

Comment: @bachu i have not idea what is osmand

Comment: @bachu Can you please explain in more detail the "osmand"

Comment: @bachu Using osmand is not a solution, since it'd still be the same OpenStreetMap dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like even Google Maps has very incomplete data for this area, and the Google Maps API doesn't permit offline use. OpenStreetMap is fairly unique in offering offline data downloads - it's definitely the most complete project of its type, if not the only project of its type.

If you're in a position to walk the streets or find a paper map of the area, it would be a great help to the community if you added to the OpenStreetMap data. It's remarkably quick and easy to do - just ask me if you need any help. I would offer to help enter data given a scan of a street map, but I don't know anything about Arabic, much less how to type it.

Comment: Is there a faster way than entering the street name one after the other on OpenStreetMap? thank u

Comment: @hamidrezahaajhoseini Not really, except for trying to get in contact with the local community. Or even trying to create a local community in the first place.

Comment: @scai  If this is the best and last way I can only enter the name of the places that I need them.Is this  a right thing?

Comment: @hamidrezahaajhoseini You can enter as much or as little data as you want into OpenStreet map - is that what you're asking?

Comment: @scai Because the area this place is great and I did not have enough time,also I just need some specific route and the location

Comment: @hamidrezahaajhoseini Yes, feel free to add new data to OSM. But don't add data from copyrighted sources like Google Maps. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners%27_guide and http://learnosm.org/en/beginner/